# Problem with firebase libraries in android studio

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication, annotations

1- My problem is simple: I want to add this library to my application:

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.2.0'
```

But unfortunately, when it is installed and synchronized, the codes for this library are:

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
```

It turns red and an error appears in its codes, and as you know, most of these codes are in AdMob advertisements.
Note: I tried using an older version of the library: firebase-auth, and the error from the annotation library disappeared, but the application no longer works and a very long error report appears.

2- I also use this library:

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
```

If you use a recent version such as:

```
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.3.1'
```

The previous problem also occurs.

How can this problem be solved? I do not know. I have asked AI repeatedly and have not found a solution

Comment: So you basically say that when you add the `firebase-auth` dependency those imports doesn't work anymore?

Comment: @AlexMamo Exactly, I spent all day solving the problem and I couldn't.

Comment: Never encounter such a problem. Those imports are from different classes and different packages.

Comment: @AlexMamo This is what I thought, but once I add firebase-auth or upgrade firebase-messaging to 23.3.1 this is what happens unfortunately, I don't really understand why.

Comment: @AlexMamo If you have a little time, I can share my computer in AnyDesk so you can see the problem for yourself.
Knowing that the application works without any problems without adding firebase-auth

Comment: Write me on LinkedIn.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have sent you